# How to run a java GUI at startup in IceWM?

Tags: java, linux, window-managers

I have been trying to run java based GUI onBoot in IceWM linux, tried to run it through different runlevels..rc3, rc4, and rc5 but couldn't run it.
here what I am trying..

`sudo java -jar /path/to/jar` in a `/etc/init.d/script` and linking it like

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/script /etc/rc3.d/S99script
```

I also made sure that the `script` has proper permissions too. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Run java app as root. Java app as root. Java based gui as root. Java gui as root through init.d. I'd better go take some sleep.

Comment: @baldrs tried it..btw down vote hurts.

Comment: Never run java as root, and never start gui from init scripts. Start from ~/.xinitrc or ~/.xprofile

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc

Comment: @baldrs IceWM do not have `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xprofile`

Comment: It is your X server who has them, specifically `xinit` script

Comment: @baldrs hm...I will check and try. Btw I got my solution. So upvote will be obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the solution! Apparently it was the `sudo` that was making problem..

So I referenced `/path/to/java/binaries` into `/etc/sudoers/` file and started `java` file from `/home/loggeduser/.profile` (I did this because there is only one user to my system) and done..rebooted and I have the Java GUI running.

Answer (score 1):

```
1)login with your user then use "ls -a" command.you can find .bash_profile file.
2)suppose still you dont have then create manually "vi .bash_profile" in your home directory(eg. vi /home/user/.bash_profile)
3)give 755 permission to bash_profile .(chmod 755 /home/user/.bash_profile)
4)then edit vi .bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=(Path of ur java location- {eg. /opt/jdk1.6.0_45})
export PATH=$PATH:(Path of ur java location- {eg. /opt/jdk1.6.0_45})
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

:wq (save and exit)

5)run .bash_profile (sh .bash_profile)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 For Linux  
  +Go to Home directory of user.(eg:- cd /home/user)
  +every user having ".bash_profile" file in home directory.(ls -a --> to check   hidden (.)file)  
  +you can give path or export java in ".bash_profile.  
  eg:- vi /home/user/.bash_profile  
  # .bash_profile  
  # Get the aliases and functions  
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then  
  . ~/.bashrc  
  fi  
  # User specific environment and startup programs  
  export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_45  
  export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.6.0_45  
  #export JBOSS_HOME=/jbossdev/brms-standalone-5.3.1/jboss-as  
  #export PATH=$PATH:/jbossdev/brms-standalone-5.3.1/jboss-as/bin  
  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin  
  export PATH  
  :wq!  
  +then grant 755 permission to .bash_profile file (chmod -R 755 /home/user/.bash_profile).  
  +execute sh .bash_profile.  
  so now you can run it through different runlevels..rc3, rc4, and rc5.
```